# Using Web API redirect to angular html page

Tags: asp.net, angular, rest, api

I want to redirect an HTML page using WEB API. I'm using ASP.Net Web API as a back-end and a front-end is on Angular 5. Here is my code. Here is my updated API source code.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public string[] Payment(string uri)
{
    try
    {
        RegistrationRequestX reg = new RegistrationRequestX();
        reg.Customer = "Test Api";
        reg.Channel = Channels.Web;
        reg.Language = "EN";
        reg.Amount = 10;
        reg.OrderID = "1234";
        reg.OrderInfo = "test info";
        reg.OrderName = "testing order";
        string retPath = uri;
        retPath = retPath.Replace("payment", "confirmation");
        reg.ReturnPath = retPath;
        RegistrationResponseX res = new RegistrationResponseX();
        res = client.Register(reg);
        client.Close();
        string[] sess = new string[2];
        sess[0] = paymentPortalURL;
        sess[1] = transactionID;
        return sess;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the complete code , it's not possible to guess

Comment: Why you don't return the url as json response from the action method using Url.Action()

Comment: @Niladri updated code has been posted.

Comment: @mbadeveloper will you elaborate??

Answer (score 0):

You can return the redirect uri back to angular client with status code 302.
At angular, you should check the returned status code. If it is 302 then redirect to returned redirect url.

Comment: how can i do that do you any example code, or link??

Answer (score 0):

Use the window.location.href in your angular to set the first element of the array that you return to redirect to the Url that you expected

Comment: yes I do but It can show an error I confirmation page. " cannot POST subscription/confirmation"

Comment: You need to build the full url in the sess[0] = paymentPortalURL

Comment: yes its working on fire-base but not working on azure PAAS.

Answer (score 0):

You can change a return type of the cotroller method on `IHttpActionResult` and return using `Ok` and `Redirect` methods, inherited from `ApiController`.

For example see code below if you want to either return `string[]` with ok code (200) or a redirect (302) with `Location` response header with provided redirect link, depending on some condition:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Payment(string uri)
{
    string[] sess = ...

    if (someRedirectCondition)
        return Redirect("http://a.link.to.your.html.page");
    else
        return Ok(sess); // A method type is inferred to Ok<string[]>(string[] content)
}
```

Comment: I want to return sess because there are two things in it paymentURL and Transaction ID.

Comment: @razasarwar You want to return a client redirect to paymentURL and pass Transaction ID at the same time? The problem here is if a client follows the redirect link in a standard way, your response body (with Transaction ID inside) will be lost.

Comment: what can I do to resolve this issue. I want to replace the string in uri from payment to confirmation and after payment process I want to redirect to confirmation page.

Comment: @razasarwar you can pass transaction id as an URL parameter of payment URL. So in controller `return Redirect("http://your-payment-URL?transactionId=...");`. However, you'd need to amend your payment page to process this transaction id URL parameter.

Comment: thanks @stop-cran its working fine but, the thing still not happen what I need